# MySQL: Ordering of columns when using a wildcard with group by has odd behavior

Tags: mysql, group-by, mysql-workbench

What is the difference between these two MySQL statements?

Works:

```
select *, count(mycol) c from mytable group by mycol;
```

Doesn't work:

```
select count(mycol) c, * from mytable group by mycol;
```

The first statement works as I'd expect, while the second one gives me a syntax error.  Why does the order matter?

I'm having trouble finding an answer from Google, because I'm not entirely sure if I'm asking the question correctly.

**Edit:**

Here's the sanitized error message.  I'm using MySQL Workbench, if that's relevant.

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* from mytable group by id' at line 1

Comment: If you get a syntax error, post the message, aso do not select columns wich are not in the group by clause. Most other rdbms does not alllow this

Comment: If the wildcard shouldn't be used with group by, why does it work in example #1?  If something works as expected, isn't reasonable to assume people will use it?  Is it a bug?  I'm interested in why the two statements would have different behavior.

Comment: Reproduced in MySQL 5.7 and 8.0 in [this db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8PD1192cPV9fXCY7cUEDSw/1)

Comment: @blindsnowmobile *Is it a bug* I do not know.

Comment: BTW: But why you group by an id, an id should be unique? and the count should always be one?

Comment: It's not my actual query.  I took an example and simplified/sanitized it before posting to SO.  Changing the column name to "id" was probably a poor choice.

Comment: Edited my question to change the column name.

Comment: Looks like the error message is from the first query not from the second one?

Comment: Correct, just updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just alias the table and the syntax error will go away.

```
select count(t.id) c, t.* from mytable t group by id;
```

See [this db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8PD1192cPV9fXCY7cUEDSw/1).

It looks like MySQL allows bare (unqualified) `*` only as immediatly following `SELECT`. The following query also raises a syntax error :

```
select 1, * from mytable t;
```

[The documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html) prevents against using bare `*` combined with other items in the `SELECT` list :

> A select list consisting only of a single unqualified `*` can be used as shorthand to select all columns from all tables.
>
> Use of an unqualified `*` with other items in the select list may produce a parse error. To avoid this problem, use a qualified `tbl_name.*` reference.